# natural logarithmic to asymptotic order

Tags: algebra-precalculus, asymptotics

Say we have an equation

$\lambda_{\epsilon}(s)=-\frac{1}{\pi s^2}\ln(1-\epsilon)$

$\forall s\in (0,(M \mathcal{k})^{-\frac{1}{\alpha}})$

where $s$ can be obtained by $s=(M \mathcal{k})^{-\frac{1}{\alpha}}$

How can we simplify the equation

$\lambda_{\epsilon}(s)=-\frac{1}{\pi}(M \mathcal{k})^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}\ln(1-\epsilon)$

into

$\lambda_{\epsilon}(s)=\frac{1}{\pi}(M \mathcal{k})^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}\epsilon + \Theta(\epsilon^2)$

Is it using Sterling approximation to get the asymptotic order expression?

Can someone teach me or give some hints regarding how we can simplify that equation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just using a Taylor series expansion of $\ln(1-\epsilon)$.

The Taylor series expansion is

$$\ln(1-x)=-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}$$

Hence we have

$$\begin{align}
\lambda_{\epsilon}(s)&=-\frac{1}{\pi}(M \mathcal{k})^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}\ln(1-\epsilon)
\\&=\frac{1}{\pi}(M \mathcal{k})^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\epsilon^n}{n}
\\&=\frac{1}{\pi}(M \mathcal{k})^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}\epsilon+\frac{1}{\pi}(M \mathcal{k})^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\epsilon^n}{n}
\\&=\frac{1}{\pi}(M \mathcal{k})^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}\epsilon+\epsilon^2\frac{1}{\pi}(M \mathcal{k})^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\epsilon^{n}}{n+2}
\\&=\frac{1}{\pi}(M \mathcal{k})^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}\epsilon+\Theta\left(\epsilon^2\right)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you very much!! i didn't notice that, i thought it was using the $ln$ properties, that's why i'm confused, many thx!

Comment: @m3wIsw3m glad to help :)